# How do I reference form inputs from texbox ids from my index1.htm into my table within index2.htm?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to display the URLs the user inputs in this index into the table in `index.2`. Here's my code.

index1.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function check_url(){
        //Get input value
        var elem = document.getElementById("url_input");
        var input_value = elem.value;
        //Set input value to lower case so HTTP or HtTp become http
        input_value = input_value.toLowerCase();
        //Check if string starts with http:// or https://
        var regExr = /^(http:|https:)\/\/.*$/m; 
        Test; expression;
        var result = regExr.test(input_value);
        //If http:// or https:// is not present add http:// before user input
        if (!result){
          var new_value = "http://"+input_value;
          elem.value=new_value;
        }
      }
    </script>      
    <title>
        CS310: Assignment 3 #1
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><div align="center">What are your favorite websites on the internet?</div></h1><hr> 
    <div align="center">
      <p>Please enter websites in the proper URL format.</p>
      <p>Example: (http://www.myURL.com)</p>
      <form action="index2.htm">
        Website 1:<input type="url" size="25px" id="1" form="form1"    name="website_address1" placeholder="Enter a website address"><br>
        Website 2:<input type="url" size="25px" id="2" form="form2" name="website_address2" placeholder="Enter a website address"><br>
        Website 3:<input type="url" size="25px" id="3" form= "form3" name="website_address3" placeholder="Enter a website address"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Table">
      </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is the table that is displayed. The table should display the three URLs that the user inputs into the `textboxes` in `index1.htm`.

index2.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
        CS310: Assignment 3 #1
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><div align="center">What are your favorite websites?</div></h1>
    <hr>  
    <div align= "center"><table border= "1" width = "40%"
         summary="This table lists the URLs inputted by the user.">  
      <caption><strong>Your favorite websites</strong></caption>
        <tr>
          <th><a href=target="1">Take me to Website #1</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><a href="2">Take me to Website #2</a></th>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th><a href="3">Take me to Website #3</a></th>  
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like homework from school. If so I recommend doing some research rather than asking others to do it for you.

Comment: I've got most of this done. I just need help linking the two indexes together to display the correct URLs.

Comment: I've tried defining each input with unique id names, and referencing those ids in index2.htm. My apologies for being a noob! I am new to web programming and have been stuck on this problem for a while now.

Comment: you can use local storage or server session storage (to mention 2 obvious techniques) to store information accross web pages.